# No sound after creation of the PyQt executable

Tags: python, audio, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I am looking for a way to deploy my python3/PyQt5 application on Window and I decided to use PyInstaller. I managed to get the whole thing to lauch and work pretty well, but my problem is with the sound.

I use PyQt5.QMediaPlayer to play sounds and music in my application and when I try to play music in the built executable, it just does not work properly and does not output any sound. I precise that when I use the python command line to launch the project from my project directory everything works fine.

Has someone had this issue already with this configuration ?
And if yes, how did you manage to fix the problem ?

EDIT: The error I get is `defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`

Comment: I have never used pyinstaller with PyQt5 but I had the same problem using PyQt5 + cx_Freeze. The problem was that I wasn't including the necessary PyQt5 modules to be bundled withing the application. Check if the `QMediaPlayer` is being correctly packaged.

Comment: Yes it's bundled, I have it in my hiddenimports as well. But I have an error like this `defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`